# How to pass return as a value for argument with adding a string?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-behave

I prepared this method

```py
def make_bearer_token(token_url):
    body = {
        "scope": "ingo_dev",
        "client_id": "machine__dev",
        "client_secret": "0c3b99",
        "username": "test.user",
        "password": "xxx",
        "grant_type": "pass",
    }
    response = requests.post(token_url, data=body).json()
    bearer_token = response["access_token"]
    print({'authorization: ' + 'Bearer ' + str(response)})

    return bearer_token
```

I want to pass that bearer_token to another method with string 'authorization':bearer_token 
as a header parameter. The method is looking something like that.

```py
@staticmethod
def post_request(endpoint, file, timeout=30):
    response = requests.post(endpoint, files=file_dict, timeout=timeout)
    return response
```

Comment: You have the variable. You can do with it what you like. What's the question?

Comment: How can I cast bearer_token as a header to requests.post method?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to run your `make_bearer_token()` from within your `post_request` method.
Bearer is a header so make a new `headers` dict with your Authorization header in it, and pass it as a parameter to `requests.post()`

```
def post_request(endpoint, file, timeout=30):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(make_bearer_token(endpoint))
    }
    response = requests.post(endpoint, files=file_dict, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
    return response
```

Edit: Based on your comment below, you might want to make use of class variables

```
class Uploader:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.headers = {
                "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(self.make_bearer_token(url))
            }


    def post_request(self, endpoint, file, timeout=30):
        response = requests.post(endpoint, files=file_dict, headers=self.headers, timeout=timeout)
        return response
```

Comment: ok but I have several post methods so I need to do something more complex/generic

Comment: Do all methods use the same bearer token or do you need a separate token for each? @Tequilla

Comment: the same token @Kasem

Comment: You might want to use class variables then, check updated answer

Comment: I got @staticmethod's

Answer (score 0):

Usually response access_token don't have prefix bearer. So you try this way.

```
import requests
bearer_token = response["access_token"]
hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer_token}
data = {'key' : 'value'}
url = 'https://next.url.com'
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=hed)
print(response)
print(response.json())
```

Please try this. Let me know you feedback on the same.

Comment: thanks but my make_bearer_token method works fine and I get 'Beare sometoken' what Ive asked for is how to cast that bearer to different method where I could reuse it(maybe parameter) + add authorization string next to him :)